# Need a PowerShell command to update the .NET Core Project's (Assembly or File) version

Tags: powershell, .net-core, tfs, project

Using PowerShell script, I am able to read the Team Foundation Server workspace version numbers.
Now I would like to update the .NET Core Project's Assembly/or/File version in its properties...
I am looking for a PowerShell command that updates properties of the project .. is that even possible?

Or a command that would update one of the properties in the appsettings.json file's data
Ex:
"AssemblyVersion": "12345"

Thank you for taking the time to look at this if you are looking to help me

...and Sorry if you are looking for a solution and there is none yet

Perry

p.s.
What I am trying to achieve is the equivalent of Tortoise's "subwcrev" command to update the "AssemblyInfoTemplate"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yé!
I've done it.
And I would like to add that I got most of my info from this site ;)
See the code attached c/w comments

```
### TFS HISTORY
Set-Alias tfs "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe"
######### some commands I tried that I want to keep
### tfs history . /r /noprompt /stopafter:1 /version:W | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\OUTPUT.txt
### Get-Content "C:\temp\OUTPUT.txt"  -tail 1 | Out-File -FilePath "C:\temp\output.csv"
### $variable = Get-Content "C:\temp\OUTPUT.txt"  -tail 1 ### gets the last line
#==========================================================================
$variable = tfs history . /r /noprompt /stopafter:1 /version:W  # get the version of tfs
########## the three lines below are the result of the "tfs history" command
# Changeset User              Date       Comment
# --------- ----------------- ---------- --------------
# 97504     Dorion, Perry     2023-02-09 v#
# what I need is the "97504" number
$vlinearray = $variable.split("`r`n") # split into lines
$vspacearray = $vlinearray[$vlinearray.Length -1].split(" ")  # split the last line into space separated strings
######### for debugging purposes
# Write-Output $vspacearray[0] #get the first string of the last line 

###################################################
############ SAVES to appsettings.json ############
### not being used
# $pathToJson = "C:\Users\PDorion\Documents\DevNETCore\PNR\PEA\appsettings.json"
# $a = Get-Content $pathToJson | ConvertFrom-Json
# $a.AssemblyVersion = $vspacearray[0]
# $a | ConvertTo-Json | set-content $pathToJson
### I needed a way to find the path of the ruinning script; mine differs from my co-workers who work on the same project
### gets path of this script  i.e. "C:\Users\PDorion\Documents\DevNETCore\PNR\PEA\"
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition;
$scriptName = "\PEA.csproj";

### get the value from TFS HISTORY    
### DOTIFY the 5 digit number   ==> #.#.#.## format 
### our TFS version numbers are too big and do not jive well with Assembly number type
$splitval = $vspacearray[0].ToCharArray()
$Result = ""
$dot = ""
$dotcnt = 0
foreach ($num in $splitval) {
  $Result = "$Result$dot$num"
  $dotcnt++
  if ($dotcnt -lt 4 ) {
    $dot = "."
  }else{
    $dot = ""
  }
}

### Write-Output "Result $Result"
$projFile = "$scriptPath$scriptName";
### get Project xml content i.e. the properties
$config = (Get-Content $projFile) -as [Xml];
$ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($config.NameTable);
$ns.AddNamespace("cs", $config.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
### the following is ugly but it works
$config.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//cs:AssemblyVersion", $ns) | % {
    $node = $_;
    $node.InnerText = $Result;
}
$config.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//cs:FileVersion", $ns) | % {
    $node = $_;
    $node.InnerText = $Result;
}
### save the sucker
$config.Save($projFile);
```